# Edit category in admin issue

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, admin, ce-1.8.1.0, category

I need to generate in one of my custom module a link to a category edit page in the backend.
So I generate the url like this:

```
 $url = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/catalog_category/index', array('id'=>$category->getId()));
```

or like this:

```
 $url = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/catalog_category/edit', array('id'=>$category->getId()));
```

I get a correct url in both cases:

```
ROOT/admin/catalog_category/index/id/10/key/<security-key-here>/
//and
ROOT/admin/catalog_category/edit/id/10/key/<security-key-here>/
```

But when the page loads, for a split second I see in the edit form the data for my category or the category I previously edited and then there is an ajax call that clears my form and I'm on add mode. ('New Root Category').  The `<title>` tag of the page contains the correct category name.  On the left side tree, the correct category is selected.

The ajax call that clears the form is made to

```
`ROOT/admin/catalog_category/edit/key/<security-key-here>/?isAjax=true`
```

So there is no id parameter in the ajax call. I guess that's the problem.
How can I make this work?
<strike>This seams like a bug to me.</strike> I stand corrected. Based on David's answer this seams like a feature.

But I recall this working correctly in a really old version (don't remember which).
I tested on [ce-1.7.0.2](/questions/tagged/ce-1.7.0.2) and [ce-1.8.1.0](/questions/tagged/ce-1.8.1.0) and the result is the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding the parameter `clear` to your urls.

There is a function `isClearEdit` that is in the class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tree` This appears to stop the second load or at least load the correct category.

```
/**
 * Check if page loaded by outside link to category edit
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function isClearEdit()
{
    return (bool) $this->getRequest()->getParam('clear');
}
```

In the tree template `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/category/tree.phtml` this will add the id of the category to the url used to update the content during the call to `_renderNewTree`.

So when building your url use the following code.

```
Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/catalog_category/index', array('id'=>$category->getId(), 'clear'=>1));
```

Comment: What do you know...it works. So I need to generate the url like this `Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/catalog_category/index', array('id'=>$category->getId(), 'clear'=>1));`

Comment: It seems to be there in at least Mage 1.6 I have no earlier versions currently :)

Comment: The funny thing is that I've included this 'feature' in my module creator extension, and it works the same for any tree behaving entity that you create with it. I had no idea what the 'clear' parameter does, but included anyway...and it works. :)